# curl cannot load localhost: "404 Not Found" answer

Tags: curl, nginx

I am running Ubuntu 20.04,
and when I try to connect to localhost using `curl` with the command:

`curl -v localhost`

I get the result:

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Sat, 22 Oct 2022 08:20:39 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 146
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Here's output from `netstat -anpee | grep :80`:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          614515     -
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          612479     -
```

What's wrong?

How do I fix it?

Comment: Can you check the output of `curl -v http://localhost` and share it?

Comment: Is there any app listening on port 80? Nginx? Apache? You can check it by `netstat -anpee | grep :80`

Comment: The output of `curl -v http://localhost` is exactly the same

Comment: The output of `netstat -anpee | grep :80` is : ```tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          614515     -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          612479     -    ```

Comment: I do not see the app that is listening on port 80, however, if it is indeed Nginx then @roaima 's answer is correct.

Comment: It could be something simple as wrong rights on the filesystem. Your nginx is working and returning the 404. Try to look in the webserver logfiles for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You've installed nginx on your local system and it's running. However, either it has virtual hosts that do not include `localhost` or you do not have a valid document root from which it can serve content.

Look in the webserver error log for further details.